# Push to github and gitlab erros

Tags: git, push, gitkraken

I'm trying to push to my GitHub repository (i have also tried pushing to a GitLab repository) and it isn't working. I have been using GitKraken, and i get an error "malformed URL" then lists the URL I am trying to push to. I have also tried pushing through git commands and i get the error "fatal: Unable to look up https (port 9418) (No such host is known. )"

I can't find much online about this, what is the error?

Edit:
It's a private repository. The URL is https://github.com/egroeg121/App-Budgey.git
On GitKraken I am just trying to push a previous commit that hasn't gone up yet. It says malformed url

On git I have committed the changes. I then use "git remote add origin https://github.com/egroeg121/App-Budgey.git" to try to set that as the working url. It gives me the error fatal:remote origin already exists. Then if I try to push i get the error i previously talked to.

Comment: Can you show us the git remotes you're trying (and failing) to push to please?

Comment: share all the information and commands which you are trying, also if its public or private repository ?

Comment: I encountered the same problems days ago, and I just switched to ssh and the error disappeared. This can be a good workaround.